# Cannot recover from stack overflow in gui

Tags: python, timer, wxpython, pyserial

My code runs for two minutes then gives this error:

> Fatal Python error: Cannot recover from stack overflow.
>   Current thread 0x000001d4 (most recent call first):

I m using wxpython and take the data from serial port ('COM9') which i have infinite data. I use `wx.Timer` and `list.append`.

For this not to give a stack overflow I delete my list using timer. During 2 minutes i run the code, everything is fine. But even though I delete the list and the length of my list is only 76, my app freezes and doesn't continue.

Maybe I should try `wxCallAfter` and `wxCallLater` or "threading and processing" in wx, but in wx threading and processing aren't recommended).

Or maybe I shouldn't use `append.list` and delete it later? If the problem because of my data structure, what should I use instead?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

import wx
from gui import *
#import _pickle as pickle
import pickle
import serial
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.pyplot
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from test.test_zipfile import StoredBadCrcTests
import time
print("0")

ser = serial.Serial('COM9',9600)
fig, ax= plt.subplots() 
x=[]
y=[]

x1=[]
x2=[]

y1=[]
y2=[]

i=0  

storage=[]

class selam ( MyFrame1 ):
    print("1")

    def __init__( self, parent ):

        MyFrame1.__init__ ( self, parent)
        print("here")
        self.m_timer1 = wx.Timer()
        self.m_timer1.SetOwner( self, 1 )
        self.m_timer2 = wx.Timer()
        self.m_timer2.SetOwner( self, 2 )
        self.m_timer3 = wx.Timer()
        self.m_timer3.SetOwner( self, 3 )
        self.m_timer4 = wx.Timer()
        self.m_timer4.SetOwner( self, 4 )


        # Connect Events
        self.Bind( wx.EVT_TIMER, self.timer1, id=1 )
        self.Bind( wx.EVT_TIMER, self.timer2, id=2 )
        self.Bind( wx.EVT_TIMER, self.timer3, id=3 )
        self.Bind( wx.EVT_TIMER, self.timer4, id=4 )

    def __del__( self ):
        pass

    def tgl1( self, event ):
        if self.m_timer1.IsRunning():
            self.m_timer1.Stop()
            print("timer 1 stopped")
        else:
            print("tgl_timer 1 starting...")
            self.m_timer1.Start( 1000 )

    def tgl2( self, event ):
        if self.m_timer2.IsRunning():
            self.m_timer2.Stop()
            plt.close()
            print("timer 2 stopped")
        else:
            print("tgl_timer 2 starting...")
            self.m_timer2.Start( 501 )

    def tgl3( self, event ):
        if self.m_timer3.IsRunning():
            self.m_timer3.Stop()
            plt.close()
            print("timer 3 stopped")
        else:
            print("tgl_timer 3 starting...")
            self.m_timer3.Start( 2000 )

    def tgl4( self, event ):
        if self.m_timer4.IsRunning():
            self.m_timer4.Stop()
            plt.close()
            print("timer 4 stopped")
        else:
            print("tgl_timer 4 starting...")
            self.m_timer4.Start( 1000 )


    ########## data and all code has to written inside of timer(1,2,3,4..)




    def timer1( self, event ):
        print("1")  

        for line in ser:
            storage.append(line)


            #===================================================================
            # f1 = open('C:\\Users\\GCS-User\\Desktop\\obj_pi','wb')
            # pickle.dump(line,f1)
            # 
            # f2=open('C:\\Users\\GCS-User\\Desktop\\obj_pi','rb')
            # print(pickle.load(f2))
            #===================================================================


    def timer2( self, event ):
        print("22")
        del storage[:]

    def timer3( self, event ):
        print("333")

    def timer4( self, event ):
        print("4444")            
        def sV_sat(i): 
            #print("a")    
            for line in storage:
                print("b")
                print("storage_len:",len(storage))
                data = line.split(b",")
                #print("data_0:",data[0])
                if data[0] == b'$GNGGA':
                    print("c")
                    altitude=data[9]
                    timm=data[1]
                    tim=float(timm)
                    tim=tim+30000

                    hour = tim//10000
                    minute = (tim//100)%100
                    second = tim%100
                    zaman = hour*3600 + minute*60 + second                        
                    altitude=float(altitude)
                    x.append(zaman)
                    y.append(altitude)                   
                    ax.plot(x,y)                                         
        ani8 = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,sV_sat)

        plt.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(0)
    frame = selam(None)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you would get that crash, but the code is not complete enough to run, so help will be limited (minimal, complete example please!)  Do you get a crash if you take out the FuncAnimation call?  You get one "timer4 event", then run the animation to repeatedly call SV_sat -- is that what you want?  I don't see how you are reading in new data -- are all 4 timers running at the same time?

Comment: i tried what you said and used plotting inside while True: and no way, same error. It s not about FuncAnimation, i think. And i realized that i have an different error too which is (`maximum recursion depth exceed in comparison`). For solving this error i tried `import sys` then `sys.setrecursionlimit(2^30)`. It just extend the running time from 2 min to 6min. Not much. Then crash and same error. Normal limit for **recursionlimit** is 1000. Did i give this value too much? If so, how can i be ensure for the supposing value?

Comment: Well, that seems like a very high recursion limit to me.  I have no idea why you have 4 timers.  Earlier, I pointed to example that might be useful to start from, and it seems you ignored that....  Without complete code and a complete error message, it is very difficult to guess what is going on.  Please produce a minimal, complete example that shows the problem, and include the full traceback.

Comment: Sir, i looked what your suggested works. Thanks a lot. It really helped me and solved my timer problem. I transfer my plot type from matplotlib to yours **wxmplot**. I didnt understand why matplotlib freeze and run just 2-6min even though my script is indifferent to running one (just matplotlib switch to wxmplot). However matplotlib has a various features like mplcursors.cursor, time formatter, plt.imread.. Can i use them within wxmplot? Or what kind of a way do you suggest me? By the way, **i really really thank you**

Comment: in general one *can* mix wxmplot and calls to the matplotib API (but not the pylab interface). wxmplot does have some cursor functions built in as well as time-formatting and image display.  Whether the built-in functionality is sufficient or you need to drop down to the matplotlib API depends on what you're trying to.